# C# WinCE How to get ContextMenu selected item (highlighted, before click on it)

Tags: c#, .net, windows-ce

Good day!
There is menu (ContextMenu), have hardware keys (arrows and Enter).
**The problem is as follows:**
When key is pressed, a menu appears, on it is possible to move up and down - menu items are highlighted, but ...
Nothing more is not working. I need to select the highlighted menu item by pressing the right arrow, as if we click on it. In an extreme case, can be performed using the key Enter, since menu is modal and is not closed by pressing the right arrow.
How to solve it or at least in what side to look?
Thank you in advance for adequate answers.